# Get a Facebook stream post by post_id

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-fql

I want to get the details (contents, user info) of a post that was made on a fan page's stream.

I have the post_id variable but don't see any method/api call where I can pass in a post_id to get the post contents.

The only thing that seems possible is getting the entire stream and comparing the post_id item by item... which is slow and inefficient.

Anyone had this problem or know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to generate an [FQL](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FQL) statement and pass it to the [Fql.query API](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fql.query) method.

Specifically, you want to query the [stream table](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream_%28FQL%29) filtering on the the post_id.

If you need extra information, you will probably need to call [Fql.multiquery](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fql.multiquery), using the results from the previous queries (as filters once you get the post, it will have the user, and so on, and so on).